# Can't implement waitForAngular to Selenium

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, protractor

We use Selenium WebDriver and Java for our framework. We need to add waitForAngular() method. At first I found source code of Protractor:

```
var waitForAngular = function(rootSelector, callback) {
    var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);
    try {
        if (window.getAngularTestability) {
            window.getAngularTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
            return;
        }
        if (!window.angular) {
            throw new Error('window.angular is undefined. This could be either ' +
                'because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves ' +
                'client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor\'s ' +
                'bootstrapping. See http://git.io/v4gXM for details');
        }
        if (angular.getTestability) {
            angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
        } else {
            if (!angular.element(el).injector()) {
                throw new Error('root element (' + rootSelector + ') has no injector.' +
                    ' this may mean it is not inside ng-app.');
            }
            angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser').
            notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        callback(err.message);
    }
};
 var rootSelector = arguments[0];
 var callback = arguments[1];
 waitForAngular(rootSelector, callback);
```

I injected it in my framework, using JavaScriptExecutor driver:

```
public void waitForAngular() {
    this.jsExecutor.executeAsyncScript(
        waitForAngularJSScript, rootElement);
}
```

As rootElement I tried to use "body", "[ng-app]". But it doesn't work. I have exception

> Error: ng:test
>   Testability Not Found
>   no injector found for element argument to getTestability

[Link to description of exception](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/test)

in the:

```
angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
```

I'm not strong in Angular, so maybe you could helpe me where I can find resolving.